# Javascript Firebase Realtime Database typeError: newChildren.insert is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

i cannot push, set, update, on my realtime Database in firebase. The code is below, thank you very much for your help.

`imports:`

```
import { serverTimestamp, getDatabase, onChildAdded, push, set, update, runTransaction, get, ref as dbRef } from "firebase/database";
import { db } from "@/config/firebaseConfig";
```

the db from the firebaseConfig is just the `getDatabase(app)`

the `set()` throws the error

```
async sendMessage() {
   if (this.messageText.trim().length === 0) return;

    const chatRef = dbRef(db, `chats/${this.chatId}`);
    const snapshot = await get(chatRef);


    const newMessageRef = await push(chatRef);

    const newMessageKey = newMessageRef.key;

    const newMessage = {
        id: newMessageKey,
        sender: this.currentUser.uid,
        text: this.messageText.trim(),
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    };

    console.log("newMessageRef:", newMessageRef);
    console.log("newMessage:", newMessage);

    await set(newMessageRef, newMessage);
```

the error:

> caught (in promise) TypeError: newChildren.insert is not a function     at IndexMap.ts:147:30     at map (obj.ts:50:21)     at Proxy.addToIndexes (IndexMap.ts:115:24)     at Proxy.updateImmediateChild (ChildrenNode.ts:156:38)     at Proxy.updateChild (ChildrenNode.ts:180:19)     at viewProcessorApplyUserOverwrite (ViewProcessor.ts:486:34)     at viewProcessorApplyOperation (ViewProcessor.ts:103:22)     at viewApplyOperation (View.ts:213:18)     at syncPointApplyOperation (SyncPoint.ts:107:9)     at syncTreeApplyOperationHelper_ (SyncTree.ts:726:9) (

i tried the old and new api.
my rules are set to true for read and write.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that there might be an issue with the data being passed to the set() method. Specifically, it seems that the newMessageRef variable is not a valid reference to a location in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Instead of using newMessageRef as the first argument to set(), try passing chatRef.child(newMessageKey) instead. This should create a new child node under the chats/${this.chatId} location with the specified key.

```
async sendMessage() {
if (this.messageText.trim().length === 0) return;

const chatRef = dbRef(db, `chats/${this.chatId}`);
const snapshot = await get(chatRef);

const newMessageRef = push(chatRef);
const newMessageKey = newMessageRef.key;

const newMessage = {
    id: newMessageKey,
    sender: this.currentUser.uid,
    text: this.messageText.trim(),
    timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
};

console.log("newMessageRef:", newMessageRef);
console.log("newMessage:", newMessage);

await set(chatRef.child(newMessageKey), newMessage);
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your respond! it still does not work, but i figured out that i can push anything anywhere - but not inside the chats/chatid.. i have no idea why, my rules are ok..